# MySQL performing slower on 'ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100' compared to order with timestamp

Tags: mysql

Let's take following scenario.

We have

```
SELECT id 
  FROM table 
 WHERE name='name' 
 ORDER 
    BY id DESC 
 LIMIT 100
```

and the exact same query with `LIMIT 5`.

The `LIMIT 100` query takes about 0.2s and the `LIMIT 5` takes 0.008s. (With even higher LIMIT of 1000 execution time rises to 2s!)

Now we use timestamp instead of id.

We have

```
SELECT id 
  FROM table 
 WHERE name='name' 
 ORDER 
    BY timestamp DESC 
 LIMIT 100
```

and again the exact same query with `LIMIT 5`.

The `LIMIT 100` query takes about 0.4s and the `LIMIT 5` takes also 0.4s. (Higher LIMIT of 1000 doesn't affect execution time much.

The table is build as following. The `id` is the primary key and auto_increment is active. The table has 500.000 rows. There are 100 different names which doesn't change. Every 10 min we insert into our table all the names with their recent updates (with timestamps). That means our table looks as following:

```
+-----+-------+---------------------+--+--+
| id  | name  | timestamp           |  |  |
+-----+-------+---------------------+--+--+
| 1   | mark  | 2019-03-31 09:00:02 |  |  |
+-----+-------+---------------------+--+--+
| 2   | peter | 2019-03-31 09:00:02 |  |  |
+-----+-------+---------------------+--+--+
| 3   | john  | 2019-03-31 09:00:02 |  |  |
+-----+-------+---------------------+--+--+
| ... | ...   | ...                 |  |  |
+-----+-------+---------------------+--+--+
| 101 | mark  | 2019-03-31 09:10:02 |  |  |
+-----+-------+---------------------+--+--+
| 102 | peter | 2019-03-31 09:10:02 |  |  |
+-----+-------+---------------------+--+--+
| 103 | john  | 2019-03-31 09:10:02 |  |  |
+-----+-------+---------------------+--+--+
```

So after the query with name='mark' it should look like this:

```
+-----+------+---------------------+--+--+
| id  | name | timestamp           |  |  |
+-----+------+---------------------+--+--+
| 501 | mark | 2019-03-31 09:50:02 |  |  |
+-----+------+---------------------+--+--+
| 401 | mark | 2019-03-31 09:40:02 |  |  |
+-----+------+---------------------+--+--+
| 301 | mark | 2019-03-31 09:30:02 |  |  |
+-----+------+---------------------+--+--+
| 201 | mark | 2019-03-31 09:20:02 |  |  |
+-----+------+---------------------+--+--+
| 101 | mark | 2019-03-31 09:10:02 |  |  |
+-----+------+---------------------+--+--+
| 1   | mark | 2019-03-31 09:00:02 |  |  |
+-----+------+---------------------+--+--+
| ... | ...  | ...                 |  |  |
+-----+------+---------------------+--+--+
```

My question now is, why does order by `id DESC` performs so much slower with high `LIMIT` (Limit 1000 is over 2s), compared to the exact same query but ordered by `timestamp DESC` (Limit 1000 is around 0.4s).

I tried to alter the table and add index to id, but that changed nothing. 
Does the problem lies in the gaps between id's? (501,401,301...).

After three days of googling and trying different queries nothing changed, and my question on this strange behaviour is not answered yet.

Explain query with id:

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| 1  | SIMPLE      | name  | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL | 1000 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

And the explain query with timestamp:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------------+
| 1  | SIMPLE      | name  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 500000 | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------------+
```

@niklaz the id type is `int(10)`

@scaisEdge

Table Schema:

```
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| name      | varchar(10)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| timestamp | timestamp        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: that's weird, ID as integer type in this case is always faster than datetime/timestamp type

Comment: What type of integer did you use in your table for ID? INTEGER, INT, SMALLINT, TINYINT, MEDIUMINT, BIGINT?

Comment: update your question and add  your table schema and your explain plan

Comment: it might be due to query with timestamp being cached, causing it to perform faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the gap is not related  to the content of the column ID  ..  You should try adding  composite redundant  index  on your table

```
 create index  idx1 on my_table(name, id)
```

Could be the gap is related  to cached  value .. try perform the query in separated  sessions.

Comment: do you mean because of name field value duplicates? It makes sense

Comment: the explain plan don't show available index  .. so the different in not related  to data type ..  but some session/execution aspect ..  the use of a proper index  .for the where clause  and a bit of redudancy for the is could help and flat the performance ..

Comment: ... but only on the assumption that this is not innodb, right?

Comment: Wow, this did speed up my query by almost 100 times!. Thank you very much, i need to learn more about these topics, do you recommend a book where these things like composite redundant is discussed?

Comment: You can staring reading mysql doc ..  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimization-indexes.html  .. and you can find a lot of info in Internet  .. google for  "indexing technology mysql" or similar  ..